# KeyGenerator exception

Tags: java, key-generator

I've tried to implement IDEA algorithm. here is the code that i found on google:

```
package ideaalgoritam;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class IDEAalgoritam {

   public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
      String toEncrypt = "The shorter you live, the longer you're dead!";

      System.out.println("Encrypting...");
      byte[] encrypted = encrypt(toEncrypt, "password");

      System.out.println("Decrypting...");
      String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, "password");

      System.out.println("Decrypted text: " + decrypted);
   }

   public static byte[] encrypt(String toEncrypt, String key) throws Exception {
      // create a binary key from the argument key (seed)
      SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(key.getBytes());
      KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("IDEA");
      kg.init(sr);
      SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();

      // create an instance of cipher
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("IDEA");

      // initialize the cipher with the key
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);

      // enctypt!
      byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());

      return encrypted;
   }

   public static String decrypt(byte[] toDecrypt, String key) throws Exception {
      // create a binary key from the argument key (seed)
      SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(key.getBytes());
      KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("IDEA");
      kg.init(sr);
      SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();

      // do the decryption with that key
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("IDEA");
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
      byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(toDecrypt);

      return new String(decrypted);
   }

}
```

But when i run the code i get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: IDEA KeyGenerator not available
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:169)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223)
    at ideaalgoritam.IDEAalgoritam.encrypt(IDEAalgoritam.java:27)
    at ideaalgoritam.IDEAalgoritam.main(IDEAalgoritam.java:16)
```

In jdk and jre security lib folder i've added security provider bouncy castle http://prntscr.com/j516zx. But i still get this exception.
Does anyone know how can i solve this problem so that i can run this code?

Comment: Have you added a line to the `java.security` file to register the provider? http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation

Comment: Also decrypting with a newly-generated key will never work. And BTW you haven't needed bcprov-ext for IDEA since 1.50 in 2013 when the patent expired and it was moved to bcprov. And ECB is not very secure in most applications.